# PEAR Mail won't connect to gmail, throws error

Tags: email, gmail, pear, bluehost, general-network-error

Solved.  Bluehost is blocking the port and they won't unblock.  Hope this helps someone else.

---

I am using the PEAR mail script given in this code example:
[Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page)

I am on Bluehost, and when I try to connect to Gmail, I get the following error:

> Failed to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 [SMTP: Failed to connect
>   socket: Network is unreachable (code: -1, response: )]

What can I do to further debug/track this down?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host was blocking the port.